# Hilt: Get Fragment LifecycleOwner and context automagically

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I would like to automagically get the fragment context and lifecycleOwner (e.g here viewLifecycleOwner), when I inject my dependencies inside a fragment. My question is, how to do so, as there is no corresponding @FragmentContext like there is a @ActivityContext. Furthermore, I would like to dynamically assign a variable to this dependency.

### My Dependency

```
class LoginDialog(
    context: Context, // get this from fragment
    private val mLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, // get this from fragment
    private val loginTitle: LoginTitle, // define this when injecting
) : AlertDialog(context, R.style.LoginDialogTheme) {
    private var _binding: LoginLoadingScreenBinding? = null
    private val binding: LoginLoadingScreenBinding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initDialog()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun show() {
        if (isShowing) return
        _binding = LoginLoadingScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply { lifecycleOwner = mLifecycleOwner }
        super.show()
    }

    override fun dismiss() {
        _binding = null
        super.dismiss()
    }

    /**
     * Calls show internally
     */
    fun onChangeIndicator(mText: String) {
        show()
        binding.indicator = mText
    }

    private fun initDialog() {
        setTitle(loginTitle.title)
        setCancelable(false)
        setView(binding.root)
    }

    sealed class LoginTitle(@StringRes val title: Int) {
        object Login : LoginTitle(R.string.loading_login_title)
        object Registration : LoginTitle(R.string.loading_registration_title)
        object ChangingEmail : LoginTitle(R.string.user_data_changing_email)
    }

}
```

### Injection

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    // here, context is requireContext(), 
    // lifecycleOwner is viewLifecylceOwner
    // and loginTitle is LoginDialog.LoginTitle.Login
    @Inject 
    @LoginTitleLogin
    lateinit var loginDialog: LoginDialog
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve this problem by creating a hilt module and changing the constructor a bit, here is the solution:

### Dependency

```
class LoginDialog(
    private val fragment: Fragment,
    private val loginTitle: LoginTitle,
) : AlertDialog(fragment.requireContext(), R.style.LoginDialogTheme) {
    private var _binding: LoginLoadingScreenBinding? = null
    private val binding: LoginLoadingScreenBinding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initDialog()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun show() {
        if (isShowing) return
        _binding = LoginLoadingScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply { lifecycleOwner = fragment.viewLifecycleOwner }
        super.show()
    }

    override fun dismiss() {
        _binding = null
        super.dismiss()
    }

    /**
     * Calls show internally
     */
    fun onChangeIndicator(mText: String) {
        show()
        binding.indicator = mText
    }

    private fun initDialog() {
        setTitle(loginTitle.title)
        setCancelable(false)
        setView(binding.root)
    }

    sealed class LoginTitle(@StringRes val title: Int) {
        object Login : LoginTitle(R.string.loading_login_title)
        object Registration : LoginTitle(R.string.loading_registration_title)
        object ChangingEmail : LoginTitle(R.string.user_data_changing_email)
    }

}
```

### Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
object FragmentModule {

    @LoginTitle
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginDialogWithLoginTitle(fragment: Fragment) = LoginDialog(
        fragment,
        LoginDialog.LoginTitle.Login
    )

    @RegistrationTitle
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginDialogWithRegistrationTitle(fragment: Fragment) = LoginDialog(
        fragment,
        LoginDialog.LoginTitle.Registration
    )

    @ChangingEmailTitle
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginDialogWithChangingEmailTitle(fragment: Fragment) = LoginDialog(
        fragment,
        LoginDialog.LoginTitle.ChangingEmail
    )

}

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class LoginTitle

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class RegistrationTitle

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ChangingEmailTitle
```

### Usage

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment() {


    @Inject
    @LoginTitle
    lateinit var loginDialog: LoginDialog
}
```